# Perform action on collection elements combination

Tags: java, collections

I have the following (overlapsWith custom implementation for compare custom elements):

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
     for (int j = i+1; j < elements.size(); j++) {
        if(elements.get(i).overlapsWith(elements.get(j))){ 
             // do something
        }
     }
 }
```

Can I do it in more proper way without using of old java loop?

Comment: If your element type in the set is `Number`, you can sort first, and then loop the set to check equivalence. I think there is no way to check without using the loop.

Comment: Can you narrow your question?, Do you want to do this Loop Iteration in a Simple Way or in effective (performance) way?

Comment: I just want to avoid old java loop in effective way. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the "old java loop"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare every element with every other element, it can't be done without two loops. The only performance improvement is to make use of symmetry, which you already do (by setting `j = i+1`).

So unfortunately there is no better way.